# Headlights on my Mazda truck aren't working

Tags: electrical, mazda, headlight

I changed the dimmer switch on my Mazda truck and the low beams won't work but the high beams do. I've changed the headlights and checked all the fuses and relays. What should I do now?

Comment: You said you changed the dimmer switch, but did you check the main switch? You didn't put the year of the truck or even which model it is, so cannot attempt to look up the wiring diagram to look anything up for you.